# How can I list my installed snaps together with their track/risk/branch?

Tags: 22.04, snap

**Context**

I would like to list the installed snaps on my machine, together with their channel information (`<track>/<risk>/<branch>`). My intention is to store that data in a file, so that I can somehow reinstall the same snaps on a new system.

**Issue**

The built-in command `snap list` seems to be geared towards printing data to a human being, and to not have options to tweak its output to have a complete dump of some fields.

So I have a nice display ("nice" as in "pleasant to the eye") :

```
$ snap list
Name                            Version                     Rev    Tracking         Publisher       Notes
firefox                         106.0.5-1                   2067   latest/stable    mozilla✓        -
snap-store                      41.3-64-g512c0ff            599    latest/stable/…  canonical✓      -
...
```

but I don't know how to restrict this to, say, `Name / Tracking` (note: I know that part is just a `awk '{ print $1, $4 }'` one liner), or how to have the complete track specification rather than `…` in `snap-store ... latest/stable/…`.

I also tried looking around for where `snap` stores its configuration files (e.g: the ones that say: `firefox` should be updated from `latest/stable`), but I could not find config directory `/etc/snap<something>`, I had no luck looking at `man snap` or `snap help *`.

I started looking at `dpkg -L snap` to have a view of what directories/files could possibly be involved with snap, but I figured I would better ask rather than start reverse engineering on my own.

**My Question**

How can I get a list of installed snaps on my system, together with the detailed track information ?

Bonus if I can get this using only `snap` commands, but using common cli tools (`find, awk, grep, jq ...`) to get this from plain files on disk is acceptable too.

---

extra info :

```
$ snap --version
snap    2.57.5+22.04
snapd   2.57.5+22.04
series  16
ubuntu  22.04
kernel  5.15.0-52-generic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered the `snap` command is limited in how the output is formatted. You can get a full list of every snap with all the information using `--verbose`.

```
 for f in $(snap list| tail -n +2 | awk '{print $1}'); do snap info --verbose $f; done
```

This will print every snap installed with all channel information.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [@popey's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1439719/18501), here is the script I wrote to list my installed snaps :

```
for f in $(snap list| tail -n +2 | awk '{print $1}'); do
    snap info $snap |\
      grep -E -e "^(name|tracking):" |\
      awk '{ if (name) { print name"\t"$2; } name=$2 }'
done

# sample output:
# bare  latest/stable
# btop  latest/stable
# chromium  latest/stable
# gtk-common-themes latest/stable/ubuntu-22.04
```

It looks like `snap` takes forever to run `snap info`, here is one way to run this in parallel :

```
#!/bin/bash

get_snap_info () {
    local snap=$1
    snap info $snap |\
      grep -E -e "^(name|tracking):" |\
      awk '{ if (name) { print name"\t"$2; } name=$2 }'
}

export -f get_snap_info

snap list| tail -n +2 | awk '{print $1}' | parallel --keep-order get_snap_info
```